# get crawled scrapy items in a django view

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I want to launch a scrapy crawl from a django view (I know it will be blocking, it's not a concern for now, I'll handle it later with futures or something like that) AND I want to recover the scrapy items resulting from that crawl (and do stuff with them).

I don't want them stored in my db (that's what things like scrapy-djangoitem do), they're not there to stay.

Right now I'm using scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess to launch the crawl from inside django and I think signals (like scrapy.signals.item_scraped maybe?) could be the way to go, but I don't understand how to put all of this together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you offload the crawl out of Django and keep it as another JSON service your web app is working on– likely needing a higher max timeout than normal calls.

There are three ways you could approach this:

1. Use something like [ScrapyRT](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyrt) and have your Django app request the URL you put the spider server on.
2. Have Django access an SQLite database where the Scrapy spiders are configured to drop the data, and deploy your spiders to a [scrapyd](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd) server.
3. Run your spiders on Scrapinghub's Scrapy Cloud. Gives you the same as #2, but then also lets you pick up the data from by making a call to the items endpoint on the API.

Comment: I think I'll end up using ScrapyRT (answer my need for real time and I do get items in json), thank you for the advice :)